# What cannot be tracked in Setup Audit Trail?

Tags: history-tracking, activityhistory, setup-audit-log

I wonder what changes cannot be tracked in setup audit trail.
I mean that there is no info when:
 - someone deletes or edits a report
 - deletes something (Topics, Member Criteria, Rules) from Communities
 - change sender email address in Communities -> administration
How do you track these things?

Answer (score 2):

[Monitor Setup Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm) explains what *is* tracked. If it's not on this list, it's not tracked in the Setup Audit Trail.

If you need other types of tracking, you might want/need [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm). This is a paid feature that does allow you to access additional logs, including modifications to reports and so on.

---

> Company information, default settings like language or locale, and
>   company messages
>
> Multiple currency Users, portal users, roles, permission sets, and
>   profiles
>
> Email addresses for any user
>
> Deleting email attachments sent as links
>
> Email footers, including creating, editing, or deleting
>
> Record types, including creating or renaming record types and
>   assigning record types to profiles
>
> Divisions, including creating, editing, and transferring and changing
>   users’ default division
>
> Certificates, adding or deleting
>
> Domain names
>
> Enabling or disabling Salesforce as an identity provider
>
> User interface settings like collapsible sections, Quick Create, hover
>   details, or related list hover links
>
> Page layout, action layout, and search layouts
>
> Compact layouts
>
> Salesforce1 navigation menu
>
> Inline edits
>
> Custom fields and field-level security, including formulas, picklist
>   values, and field attributes like the auto-number field format, field
>   manageability, or masking of encrypted fields Lead settings, lead
>   assignment rules, and lead queues
>
> Activity settings
>
> Support settings, business hours, case assignment and escalation
>   rules, and case queues
>
> Requests to Salesforce Customer Support
>
> Tab names, including tabs that you reset to the original tab name
>
> Custom apps (including Salesforce console apps), custom objects, and
>   custom tabs
>
> Contract settings
>
> Forecast settings
>
> Email-to-Case or On-Demand Email-to-Case, enabling or disabling
>
> Custom buttons, links, and s-controls, including standard button
>   overrides
>
> Drag-and-drop scheduling, enabling or disabling
>
> Similar opportunities, enabling, disabling, or customizing
>
> Quotes, enabling or disabling
>
> Data category groups, data categories, and category-group assignments
>   to objects
>
> Article types
>
> Category groups and categories
>
> Salesforce Knowledge settings
>
> Ideas settings
>
> Answers settings
>
> Field tracking in feeds
>
> Campaign influence settings
>
> Critical updates, activating or deactivating
>
> Chatter email notifications, enabling or disabling
>
> Chatter new user creation settings for invitations and email domains,
>   enabling or disabling
>
> Validation rules
>
> Public groups, sharing rules, and org-wide sharing, including the
>   Grant Access Using Hierarchies option
>
> Password policies
>
> Password resets
>
> Session settings, like session timeout (excluding Session times out
>   after and Session security level required at login profile settings)
>
> Delegated administration groups and the items delegated admins can
>   manage (setup changes made by delegated administrators are also
>   tracked)
>
> Lightning Login, enabling or disabling, enrollments, and cancellations
>
> How many records a user emptied from their Recycle Bin and from the
>   org’s Recycle Bin
>
> SAML (Security Assertion Markup Language) configuration settings
>
> Salesforce certificates
>
> Identity providers, enabling or disabling
>
> Named credentials
>
> Service providers
>
> Shield Platform Encryption setup
>
> Mass delete use, including when a mass delete exceeds the user’s
>   Recycle Bin limit on deleted records
>
> Data export requests
>
> Mass transfer use
>
> Reporting snapshots, including defining, deleting, or changing the
>   source report or target object on a reporting snapshot
>
> Use of the Data Import Wizard
>
> Sandbox deletions
>
> Apex classes and triggers
>
> Visualforce pages, custom components, and static resources
>
> Lightning pages
>
> Action link templates
>
> Custom settings
>
> Custom metadata types and records
>
> Remote access definitions
>
> Force.com Sites settings
>
> API usage metering notification, creating
>
> Territories Process automation settings
>
> Approval processes
>
> Workflow actions, creating or deleting
>
> Visual Workflow files
>
> Packages from Force.com AppExchange that you installed or uninstalled
>
> Account team and opportunity team selling settings
>
> Activating Google Apps services
>
> Mobile configuration settings, including data sets, mobile views, and
>   excluded fields
>
> Users with the “Manage External Users” permission logging in to the
>   partner portal as partner users
>
> Users with the “Edit Self-Service Users” permission logging in to the
>   Salesforce Customer Portal as Customer Portal users
>
> Partner portal accounts, enabling or disabling
>
> Salesforce Customer Portal accounts, disabling Salesforce Customer
>   Portal, enabling or disabling
>
> Creating multiple Customer Portals
>
> Entitlement processes and entitlement templates, changing or creating
>
> Self-registration for a Salesforce Customer Portal, enabling or
>   disabling
>
> Customer Portal or partner portal users, enabling or disabling